# json-lift extract method not accessable

Tags: json, parsing, scala, lift-json

I am using json-lift that is compatible with scala 2.10 from [lift-json](https://github.com/iron9light/lift-json) but I do not seem to have access to the extract method. like this example :

```
import net.liftweb.json._
object testobject {

case class process(process_id:Int,job_id:Int ,command:String, exception:String)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
val json = parse("""
    { 
        "process_id": "2",
        "job_id": "540",
        "command": "update",
        "exception": "0"
    }
    """)

    json.extract[process] // produces an error


 }

}
```

now the class has dynamic parsing , for example the following does not produce any error (sweet):

```
json.process_id // will produce JString(2)
```

my two questions are :

1. How can I map a json object to my case class
2. How to convert JString to a regular string.

Update:
the good people at [lift](http://liftweb.net/download) have created an upgrade for scala 2.10.0 ... so you can just downloaded from their. No need for any work around.

```
import net.liftweb.json._
object testobject {

case class process(process_id:Int,job_id:Int ,command:String, exception:String)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
val json = parse("""
    { 
        "process_id": "2",
        "job_id": "540",
        "command": "update",
        "exception": "0"
    }
    """)

    val p = json.extract[process] // maps the json object to the process case class
    println(p.job_id) // will print 540



 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I show you my method to get the proper String, hope helps you:

Suppose a list of tuples with x and y values

```
val dataSet:List[(Int,Int)] = new List((0,1),(1,3),(2,6))
```

I make my JObject (`net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JObject`):

```
val jsonTmp:JObject = ("x" -> dataSet.map(k => k._1)) ~ ("y" -> dataSet.map(k => k._2)))
```

then I get my String like this:

```
val jsonString:String = compact(render(jsonTmp))
```

`compact(d:Document):String` & `render(value:JValue):Document` are from json package.

And this is the resulting String (triple quotes are just for code formatting):

```
"""  {"x":[0,1,2],"y":[1,3,6]}  """
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
val process_id = json.process_id match { case JString(s) => s.toInt }
```